# Random numbers on output

Tags: c++, function

I am a relative beginner with C++ and currently I am learning how to do functions. Recently I received the following exercise:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
using namespace std; 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{ 
    int a,sum=0; 
    cout<<"Enter a number:"; 
    cin>>a; 

    int func(int x);
    sum=func (a );

    cout<<"\n"<<sum;
}

int func(int a)
{
    int x;
    for (int i=0; i<=a; i++)
    {
        x+=i;   
    }
    return x;      
}
```

I was already given the int main part of the code in advance, what I need to do is to complete the `int func` part so the code would execute properly. If I run this code I just get some random numbers. What the `func` should do is to return the sum of all natural numbers limited by the number imputed by the user. Could you tell me how would I have to change this code so it would work properly? Thank you for any feedback!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Mistake:**

The `int x` is not initialized so it will lead to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and `x` will give you any random value instead of the correct sum.

**Possible Solution:**

Before you make any increment to the variable `x`, Initialize it with zero to ensure that it will contain only those values which you want to store.

**Updated Code:**

```
int func(int a)
{
    int x = 0; //updated statement

    for (int i=0; i<=a; i++)
    {
        x+=i;   
    }
    return x;      
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you a lot Itban. The issue was solved as soon as I added the "=0". A very unfortunate blunder from my side for failing to notice the fallacy in the code. Regardless I compliment how you structured the solution, it is very clear and concise.

Comment: You are welcome @Noir :) I just tried to provide a clear solution

Answer (score 2):

you must init *x* in *func* body

```
int x = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

`int x` is not initialized. Thus leads to undefined behaviour (This is why you got random numbers). You have to initialize it using one of those:

```
int x=0;
int x(0);
int x{0};
```

Comment: int x{0}; //This statement is possible from c++11 only .Also , it will not allow narrowing .